# How to achieve two different behaviors with the same button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a click event, which changes the identifier of a button. I created a second click event on the same button but this time with the new id. When I click the button, a second time. I always have the first behavior with the old id. Here is the code to better illustrate this example. The idea is to do two different behaviors with the same button

```
$('#button').on('click',function () {
    $(this).attr('id','buttonBis');
});

$('#buttonBis').on('click',function () {
    alert('here');
});
```

Comment: 2 id for 1 button?

Comment: Like @Rory McCrossan have said. I shoud change the classes and not the ids.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're changing the identifiers dynamically then you will need to use delegated event handlers:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {
  $(this).attr('id', 'buttonBis');
});

$(document).on('click', '#buttonBis', function() {
  alert('here');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button">Click me twice to see the alert()</button>
```

Note that dynamically changing `id` attributes is not considered a very good idea, and should avoided where possible. I'd suggest adding/removing classes would be a much better alternative.

Comment: Much better than another one . +1

Comment: Yes, you are right. Cause the id make the item unique. I will change that by adding some classes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create function to assign event to new button id and remove attached (prevent duplication of)  event by replacing the dom node by its colne ,

```js
$('#button').on('click',function () {
    $(this).attr('id','buttonBis');
    //clone the node then reissign to the same node
    // which removes the previous attached events
    var self = this.cloneNode(true);
    $(this).replaceWith(self);
    newevent();
});


var newevent = function() {
  $('#buttonBis').on('click',function () {
      alert('here');
   });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button" >Click Me twice </button>
```

Comment: Just FYI instead of `this.parentNode.replaceChild...` jQuery has a `replaceWith()` method you can use